# Is it possible to make cash on delivery depends on shipping address

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

I've made my admin configuration for **cash on delivery payment** as applicable only to specific country i.e, USA

Below my cases in checkout page,

```
Billing Country => USA, Shipping Country => USA | COD Available
Billing Country => USA, Shipping Country => OTHER | COD Available
Billing Country => OTHER, Shipping Country => USA | COD Not Available
Billing Country => OTHER, Shipping Country => OTHER | COD Not Available
```

So this clearly shows that COD configuration of applicable country is pointing only to billing address.

Any way to make this condition to check shipping country instead of billing country ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out,

Event in config.xml,

```
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <disable_cod_non_indian_shipping>
                        <class>Caritor_Mobileapp_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>disableCOD</method>
                    </disable_cod_non_indian_shipping>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
```

My Observer.php

```
public function disableCOD($observer){
        $result=$observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $MethodInstance=$observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if($quote && $quote->getId()):
            $ShippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
            $country_id = $ShippingAddress->getCountryId();
            if($MethodInstance->getCode()=='cashondelivery'){
                if($country_id == 'US'){                
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {
                    $result->isAvailable = false;
                }
            }
        endif;
    }
```

Above code makes cash on delivery payment visible only if shipping country is set to United States.

Note: This will set cash on delivery payment available even it's disabled from magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a extension that observes payment_method_is_active event and decide if your method is active or not

Comment: I did it and it worked partially. Anyhow thanks for the hint.